# The meaning of "course"

Tags: sens

"J'ai fait une course" - does this mean:

1. I did a run or I went running
   Or
2. I ran an errand or I did an errand ?

I'm trying to understand the context we can use to understand what is the meaning of "course" or should we always clarify running as "course à pied" ?

Comment: Usually the context will be obvious: *j'ai fait une course cette année : le marathon de Paris* / *j'étais parti faire une course ce matin quand mon téléphone a sonné*... And *course à pied* is not always substitutable for *course* (neither is "running" for "race").

Answer (score 5):

It might be either depending on the context.

*J'ai fait les courses* is almost always "I run errands".
*J'ai une course à faire* is about an errand too.

On the other hand:

*Il fait la course en tête* (he is leading) is obviously about a race (*course* is more a race than a run.)

*Course* might also have specialized meanings. When a taxi driver *fait une course*, that means he is on a ride.